# Custom data of vertices, Vertex Layers

Tags: python, bmesh

I found this answer (first answer) [Python: assign custom tag to vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7094/python-assign-custom-tag-to-vertices?answertab=active#tab-top)

I'm pretty excited of this. But I have some questions:

1) How to get all vertices which have 'my_id' custom data?

2) How to remove 'my_id' custom data from all vertices. To clear vertices from unnecessary custom data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
 [i for i in bm.verts if i[my_id]]
```

This will work because any int value other than `0` will return `True`. Therefore there's an assumption that you aren't using the value `0` for anything meaningful.

2)

Custom id data is removed after `bm.free()`. I don't know if it can be wiped before.

---

for the sake of completeness

```
>>> import bmesh
>>> bm = bmesh.new()
>>> obj = bpy.context.active_object
>>> bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
>>> my_id = bm.verts.layers.int.new('id')
>>> bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
>>> bm.verts[0][my_id]
0
```

This shows that even before you assign a specific value to your `layer.int` for that vertex, it will already have a default 0.

Comment: Also, could you say how to remove only one vert from the custom data? Say, "bm.verts[0]" vert.

Comment: i'm not too sure, else I would be more elaborate in my answer. It might be that you should just tag the ones you want to ignore as `-1` or something as a token. The [documentation is quite sparse](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bmesh.types.html?highlight=bmesh.types.bmlayeraccessvert#bmesh.types.BMLayerAccessVert) and doesn't mention removal as far as I've been able to find.

Comment: Also, a question:
If i remove 'my_id' entire from layers - will the values still be in mesh memory?
I mean this "bm.verts.layers.int.remove(my_id)"

Comment: @mifth sorry. comments are not really for asking questions and exchanging answers. The best thing to do is to ask another question with a bit of code to help 'set the scene' (even if you think it overlaps). This helps keep information modular and easier to search on accurate Question titles.

Comment: In any event, the answer to that question is something you could find for yourself by trying.. setting up a small scene with a icosahedron, adding the above code and experimenting to see if the data persists or not. I assume it does not.