# Assign custom attributes to each individual vertex

Tags: export, vertices, vertex-groups

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create a row of vertices to render as Christmas lights. Each vertex has its own x, y, z values, but I would like to add a fourth attribute to use as brightness.

Here's a simplified visualization of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Each vertex has its own custom attribute so I can assign it as a brightness from 0 (dim) to 3 (brightest).

Is there any way to add a fourth attribute that doesn't involve vertex groups? Exporting vertex groups via JSON gives me four arrays of a binary nature:

```
"Group 0": [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
"Group 1": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
"Group 2": [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
"Group 3": [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What I need is just one array because the values won't necessarily be in discrete integers:

```
"Groups" : [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Question:**

- How do I assign a custom attribute to each vertex via the GUI?

I've seen [answers that need use of the BMesh module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7094/python-assign-custom-tag-to-vertices?answertab=active#tab-top), but I don't know scripting, and I need to edit each vertex individually (hopefully via the GUI).

I saw the `Custom Properties` dropdown, which looked very promising, but I cannot assign individual values to each vertex, it only assigns a single property to the entire object.

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to use the exported data? I think it would be easier to create an object at each location with a custom value, then have a script to export the format you want. Also each vertex group has a weight which is between 0.0 and 1.0, so you shouldn't get only 0 or 1 in the vertex group export.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I didn't know you could change vertex weights! This is what I was looking for. I had to assign values as `0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3` and then remove "0." from each JSON value to transform to integers, but it works! (By the way, I'm using THREE.js exporter to use the JSON data in Three.js)