# Change edge length using BMesh Operators

Tags: bmesh

I have read some articles about access to the Mesh primitives like edge and vertex, but all those are outdated today for my understanding (such as [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7096/75634)). My question is how by utilising python script (and [BMesh Operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html) I guess) to set precise length for the exact edge of the Mesh. I am thinking about using the python script like parametric modelling (like do Fuson 360), I want to change the value of the parameter to change part of the mesh.

Comment: Needs detail. Lots of ways to resize an edge. Can move one or both end verts.

Comment: I want to move both vertices at the same distance from the edge centre but toward opposite directions